# How to copy file path of several PDFs to clipboard?

Tags: copy-paste

The Shift + right click > "Copy as path" method doesn't seem to work when copying a list of PDF file paths, does anybody have any ideas as to how i could do this?

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7. I am selecting a list of files in Windows Explorer, holding shift while right-clicking, clicking "Copy as path". When pasting into Notepad, I get each path of PDF files separated by a linebreak. Try pasting into Notepad. Perhaps you are pasting into a field which can only accept one line.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 as well. When pasting into notepad, I get only the last path shift-right-clicked/copy as path, not the two previous selections. I like the batch file method, however.

Comment: This seems to work on my computer but not my colleagues, i will try your other solution on his. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, your method should work within Windows Explorer. There is another way to accomplish this using the Windows command line.

**Using cmd.exe**

Replace `C:\YourPath\ToFolder\` to the location of your PDF files:

`(for %i in (C:\YourPath\ToFolder\*.pdf) do @echo %~fi) | clip`

`~f` is a [batch parameter modifier](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) to show the full path of each file.
It is necessary to surround the command with parenthesis so that all lines of the output are redirected to the clipboard.